# Average Velocity

Tags: calculus

Would someone mind checking my work as my answer differs from the book and I think the book is incorrect.

starting point: $S=4t^3$

$t1 = 0$

$t2 = .1$

$t1 = 4(0)^3 = 0$

$t2 = 4(.1)^3 = .004$

$(.004-0)/(2-1) = .004/1 = .004 m/s$

While the book has $.04 m/s$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{s(t+\Delta t)-s(t)}{\Delta t} = \frac{s(t_2)-s(t_1)}{t_2-t_1} = \frac{s(.1)-s(0)}{.1} = \frac{.004-0}{.1} = .04 \text{m/s}$$

You have used the wrong time difference.

Comment: Doh, thanks didn't see that.